# Execute actions before specific commands in Apache Guacamole

Tags: shell, security, ssh, guacamole

I setup `Apache Guacamole 0.9.14` on my `CentOS 7` with `nginx` as reverse proxy to it.

I want to give limited access to some of my employees for some of my servers via `ssh`.

Some of them are `SFTP` enabled and to prevent sabotage on purpose or not I edit guacamole upload function to upload a copy of file uploaded on guacamole server itself alongside destination server.

I was wondering if I could create a copy of files getting on destination servers via `wget`, `curl`, etc.

If I can control specific commands on destination servers and do some actions before executing them, (For example backing files on guacamole server before executing any rm -rf command or creating a copy of file 'wget'ed on guacamole server), that would be great.

There are more than a thousand servers with different Linux OSs on them, so editing any server except `guacamole server` itself is impossible to do.

Any idea on how to control commands before executing on guacamole server specially on `ssh`?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [sf] or [unix.se].

Comment: @Kenster I asked my question in Server Fault, here is the link for future reference: https://serverfault.com/q/927670